# MongoDB finding documents with the MongoC driver

Tags: mongodb-query

I'm just getting started with MongoDB (using the C driver) and quickly ran into a problem. I have a collection that has multiple documents in it. I need to find out if specific documents exist. Some documents only have empty fields and I can't seem to find any way to query these documents. I've tried a bunch of different ways to set up the query, but they all fail. If my field contains data, I can find it just fine.

An example of my document with an empty field:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "$oid" : "615e069eb67a653779d584cb"
    },
    "autoServSettings" : {}
}
```

The c code I'm using:

```
mongoc_collection_t* collection = mongoc_client_get_collection(client, "db_name", "collection_name");
  
bson_t* query = bson_new();
BSON_APPEND_UTF8(query, "autoServSettings", "");

mongoc_cursor_t* cursor = mongoc_collection_find_with_opts(collection, query, NULL, NULL);

const bson_t* doc;
if (mongoc_cursor_next(cursor, &doc)) {
  // document exists;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a query that does the trick:

```
bson_t* query = BCON_NEW("autoServSettings", "{", "$exists", BCON_BOOL(true), "}");
```

I have so much to learn...